# iPhone - customizing WebKit

Tags: iphone, css, webkit, overflow

Apple has disabled the overflow CSS aspect in mobile Safari so it is not possible to scroll inside a fixed height div. This is quite annoying.

While making an iPhone native app, is it possible to access WebKit settings to turn that feature on ?

Comment: Not half as annoying as scrollbars within scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can scroll with 2 fingers.
2. If you don't want to scroll with 2 fingers, try http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-for-mobile-webkit-turns-3/16.
3. WebKit is a private framework, so you can't do anything even if you develop a native app (for AppStore).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried iScroll already but as it's more a workaround than a real solution I was hopping to solve the problem that way. Back to iScroll then.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Sorry - you'll have to use js to position things.

It's disabled because you aren't "scrolling", you are moving the viewport, so position-fixed doesn't make sense.